# How to Blink the text when a new data is added to the server using jquery?

Tags: html, jquery

I am getting the blink notification when 1 user send me a message and  when i click the . dropdown-toggle it unblinks . What i need is when i click the dropdown -toggle when 2 or 3 users sends a message at the same time, i want them to blink it too..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#indi").blink({
    delay: 100
  }); // use to blink when notification comes 
  $("#new_message").load('new_notification');
  $("#indi").load('indi');

  $('.dropdown-toggle').click(function() {
    $('#indi').unblink();
  });\\
  use to unblink when the div is clicked

  setInterval(function() {

    $("#new_message").load('new_notification');
    $("#indi").load('indi');

  }, 1000);
});
```

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
              <span class="label label-success" id="indi"></span>
            </a>
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Shouldn't there be anything that triggers that action?

Comment: i tried to write a if condition when #indi is not empty but that it didn't work it too